# Is there JTextComponent's(swing) modelToView method equivalent for Android?

Tags: java, android, swing

Title says all.

I'm in search om a method like modelToView, but for Android.

Comment: What does this method do? Not all developers worked with `Swing`.

Comment: [Java API Site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView(int))

Comment: So I don't know what is `model` in `Swing` then the docs doesn't mean anything for me.